# Inserting new sections into UITableView causing crash

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am struggling with inserting new sections into UITableView. What basically i want to achieve is:-
I am trying to create calendar where each SECTION corresponds to each YEAR. Each section is having 30 cells.

First section loads pretty well but when i go to 8th cell of first section then i try to insert new section

```
sectionNo =1; //in viewDidLoad method 

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell              forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row == 10 && indexPath.section == sectionNo-1)
{
    sectionNo = sectionNo+1;
    [mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNo-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; //APPLICATION CRASHES HERE  ERROR IS "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
"
}
   }
```

//Number of sections reads as

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return sectionNo;    //count of section
}
```

//Number of Rows per section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 12; 
}
```

//CEll for row method reads as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
return cell;
}
```

Interesting thing is sometimes when i do not scroll it rapidly then it does not crash. but if i scroll slowly from 10th row to 11 then sometimes it does not crash
WHAT I AM DOING WRONG HERE

Comment: What are the details of the crash/exception?

Comment: Hi Mike i have mentioned crash detail.Its APPLICATION CRASHES HERE  ERROR IS "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: We solved it with this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
  if(indexPath.row == 10 && indexPath.section == _sectionNo-1) 
  { 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
     [self addSectionToTableView]; 
    }); 
  } 
} 

- (void)addSectionToTableView{ 
_sectionNo++; 
 [_mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:_sectionNo-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, We need willDisplayCell method because i want to load next section as it approaches to 8th cell of previous section. Lazy loading sort of thing.Also i am increasing sectionNo.

Comment: if(indexPath.row == 10 && indexPath.section == sectionNo-1)
{ 
 [mainTable beginUpdates];
    sectionNo = sectionNo+1;
    [mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNo-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
    [mainTable endUpdates];
}

Comment: Ahh already tried now i get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 12 beyond bounds [0 .. 11]'

Comment: ah ok, then try to put first insertSections and then sectionNo++;

Comment: When i try to increase sectionNo after [mainTable endUpdates]; then Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: If after insertSections: but before endUpdates then  -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: seems that this code here is wrong: [cell.contentView addSubview:[backMonthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+indexPath.section*12]];

Comment: I tried to comment it out and just putting cell.textLabel.text = @"hello"; still crashing Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: Interesting thing is sometimes when i do not scroll it repidly then it does not crash. but if i scroll slowly from 10th row to 11 then sometimes it does not crash

Comment: where does it crash and says beyond bounds then?

Comment: [mainTable beginUpdates];
        sectionNo = sectionNo+1;
        [mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNo-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [mainTable endUpdates]; //HERE IT CRASHES

Comment: Thank you very much but it still crash same as before. I put my relative code http://pastebin.com/1q9aRmtg

Comment: I have ARC project. Just to make sure in .h file @ property (readwrite)int _sectionNo;
@ property (strong, nonatomic)UITableView *mainTable;  and in .m file @ synthesize _sectionNo, mainTable; is correct? then using _sectionNo and mainTable everywhere?

Comment: I am using @ property because SO not allowing me here to use @property

Comment: just set @ property (readwrite) int sectionNo; and @ property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *mainTable; You don't have to add the _ underlines, because ARC is doing this for you automatically, you also don't need to synthezise them in your implementation file. In your Implementation you can access these variables by adding an underline _mainTable and _sectionNo

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but it still crash on same point saying Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'  NOW I CHANGED EXACTLY WHAT YOU SAID

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33971/discussion-between-julien-klindt-and-mann)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the issue is causing with this code:

```
if(indexPath.row == 10 && indexPath.section == sectionNo-1)
{
    sectionNo = sectionNo+1;
    [mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNo-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Change that to:

```
if(indexPath.row == 10 && indexPath.section == sectionNo-1)
{

    [mainTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNo-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    sectionNo = sectionNo+1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it crashes again saying                    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: @mann: That is a different type of crash, not the previous one. Will update the answer, if I find the solution for this also.